# wear 2.0 app not appearing on wear play store

Tags: android-wear-2.0

> I am making a standalone wear app and have uploaded the wear apk in beta testing
> and have also added account in tester list but still the app won't appear in
> wear play store
>
> Can someone help me with this? i m new to android wear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are tring to use a closed beta distribution mode.
If you want your app to be found by simple search on the Play Store use an openBeta instead (everybody can search your app).
However, if you still have difficulties finding your app on the watch store you can use the following method starting directly at point (3).

If you need to stick with closed beta, you need to install the app trough the browser of your PC/MAC.

1. Use the test link of your app:
   https://play.google.com/apps/testing/**{YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME}**
   (Make sure you are logged in to the Google Play in your browser with the Google Account you authorized as a beta tester)
2. Accept to become a beta tester, and click on "Download the **{YOUR_APP_NAME}** app on Google Play" or Search it directly in the store.
3. Once you are in the Google Play listing page of your app, install it by clicking on the install button and
   selecting your device: [image]